# Rails 5 - Query association for name of 'parent' and count of 'child'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

**Models**

Users have clients, which have projects which have tasks.

I'm trying to build an array with [Name, Count] to send to a Google Chart - I have all of them but one resolved:

```
def task_by_project(user)
    task_arr = user.projects.joins(:tasks).where("tasks.completed = ?", "0").uniq.collect { |d| [d.name, d.tasks.count] }.to_a
    task_arr.unshift(['Projects', 'Uncompleted Tasks'])
    return task_arr
end
```

This query is returning 11 entries. Which is actually -all- of the entries for this user. It's bypassing the `where` completely. There is 7 uncompleted 4 completed.

Within the view I am rendering it slightly different with a loop:

```
    <% current_user.projects.uniq.each do |project| %>
      <%= link_to project.name + " || " + project.tasks.where(completed: 0).count.to_s + " tasks remaining currently", project, :class => "collection-item" %>
    <% end %>  
  </div>
```

I'm fairly confident it has to do with my misunderstanding of how to query an association this deep.

The END RESULT is I need Project's Name, and the Count of how many Tasks it has.

I do this via query by joining `Task` back to `Project` on `Project.ID` - But I'm not sure how to do that with an entire collection.

(The purpose of the 'unshift' is because other-wise I end up with a result format of `[[['Projects', 'Tasks'], [['First Record, 2] ... ]]` which isn't GCharts format. Flatter killed it off -too- much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
projects = user.projects
  .select("projects.name, COUNT(uncompleted_tasks.id) AS uncompleted_tasks_count")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks AS uncompleted_tasks ON uncompleted_tasks.project_id = projects.id AND uncompleted_tasks.completed = 0")
  .group("projects.id")
  .map { |project| [project.name, project.uncompleted_tasks_count] }
```

Comment: `completed: [0, nil]` should not be needed if the OP has set a default for the column.

Comment: I believe that if you remove the `nil`, then it won't include projects that hasn't got any tasks. If that is the intended case, the `left_joins` could also be changed to a `joins`.

Comment: Nope, since you are doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rows will be returned even if they don't have any matches in the join. I'm guessing its either a missnamed enum or a boolean column improperly defined as a integer. In both cases it should have a default as you don't want a null / indeterminate state.

Comment: @max I don't believe so, since the `.where(...)` will affect that, unless you give an `or nil` option. But there are issues anyway. For this reason I have changed my answer to a `joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN...")` option instead :-)

Comment: I think you mean `"AND tasks.completed = 0"`

Comment: @max Thank you :-) I like your profile text. Ruby also makes me happy :-)

Comment: Thanks @kaspernj - This actually solved my issue plug-n-play in so you took ample time to understand my issue. I wasn't sure if using raw SQL was Rails-friendly so I was trying to use the built-in methods but this is much better.

Comment: @DNorthrup Happy it worked out for you :-) Don't be afraid of writing a little bit of SQL once in a while ;-)

Comment: @kaspernj Thanks! Raw SQL is my preferred method, just didn't know how Rails friendly it was.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.pluck` to get the column values instead

```
user.projects.left_joins(:tasks).where("tasks.completed = 0")
    .distinct
    .pluck('users.id, users.name, tasks.count')
    .map { |a| a.pop(2) }
```

`.pluck` is far more efficient as it just queries the columns passed to pluck and returns an array of arrays instead of loading a bunch of models into memory.

```
 # => [[1, 'Frank', 0], [2, 'Muhammad', 5], [3, 'Jane', 3]]
```

However unless your name column is unique you should select the user id to weed out duplicates. `.map { |a| a.pop(2) }` gets rid of the id in the resulting arrays.

Pulling records out of the database and calling `.uniq` on them is a huge antipattern. You're pulling tons of data out of the database and then sorting out the duplicates in Ruby. This can lead to severe performance issues.

Also a better way to handle states is by using a [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
class Task
  enum :status, [:incomplete, :complete, :deleted]
end
```

Which will let you query:

```
Task.incomplete
Task.completed
```

And gives you interogration and mutation methods:

```
task.complete?
task.complete!
```

You can use it like so:

```
user.projects.left_joins(:tasks).where(tasks: Task.incomplete)
    .distinct
    .pluck('users.id, users.name, tasks.count')
    .map { |a| a.pop(2) }
```

Comment: Edited, I realized that you need to select `users.id` to get the proper distinct query. Otherwise the results will be by name so two users with the same name and count will be returned as the same row instead of two rows.

Comment: Thanks for the deep level of thought. Task.`completed` actually is an enum, and for some reason I completely forgot about the helper. For some reason I also didn't think to pluck more than one column (I didn't know it built an array)

Comment: Don’t name an enum complete - name it state or status or whatever but not something that can’t be mistaken.